# ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory php

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

My web page is not running on my system,

When checked on apache error log shows below error,

```
# tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

[Tue Jul 14 05:36:19.899752 2015] [:error] [pid 27660:tid 140637045212928] [client 50.28.66.241:50935] Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see ZendGuardLoader is not installed on your server with the PHP, Please check your php version and try to install it. You can install some php extension on cPanel server with the following command.

```
/scripts/phpextensionmgr install Zendopt
```

You can install following modules on your server with the above command.

```
[root ~ ]# /scripts/phpextensionmgr list
Available Extensions:
EAccelerator
IonCubeLoader
Zendopt
Xcache
SourceGuardian
PHPSuHosin
```